# zuluCrypt hangs when creating a luks container with a key

Tags: encryption, cryptsetup

When I create a luks container using zulucrypt, it hangs at the point of creating the file system. I have installed zulucrypt and cryptsetup.

I select 'create encrypted container in a file' or 'create encrypted container in a hard drive'

I create the container.

I then choose a key (passphrase), a luks volume type and aes.xts-plain64.512.sha512, ext4 filesystem using /dev/urandom.

I click create.

The HDD flickers for a moment then the no further progress is made.

I played around with creating a luks container via the cryptsetup command line (after some googling) and that all works. At this stage I make the following further observations.

1. On the cli, at the point of creating the filesystem I have to manually type YES (in capitals). Is zulucrypt hanging at this stage ?
2. I can mount and unmount my containers via the cryptsetup cli, but cannot mount my cli generated containers using zulucrypt, I receive a message about the key not being present.

I appreciate this post will probably need more detail, and I am happy to provide it as needed. (I wanted to keep it brief in the first instance).

Comment: Related and a possible duplicate: [How to encrypt external devices?](/q/500981/175814), specifically [this answer about LUKS](/a/500987/175814)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted `~/.zuluCrypt` and `~/.zuluCrypt-socket`, following the advice of the programs author mhogomchungu.

```
rm -rf ~/.zuluCrypt

rm -rf ~/.zuluCrypt-socket
```

Zulucrypt now does work for me and I can create, mount and use Luks encrypted containers.

I have answered my own question but all credit goes to the programs author. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Developer of zuluCrypt here.

The version of zuluCrypt you are using is too old. Update to the latest version(5.0.1) and try again. The problem you are experiencing was fixed in version 4.7.8[1](look at the first entry of the changelog)

[1] https://github.com/mhogomchungu/zuluCrypt/releases/tag/4.7.8

Comment: Hi. I tried 5.0.1 and I had the same issue. I installed 5.0.1. from the zulucrypt website, downloaded the 4 x .deb packages and installed with sudo dpkg -i. However, let me try again in my VM, maybe I did something wrong. I'll feedback shortly......

Comment: OK. I now have installed zulucrypt-dev, zulucrypt1, zulucrypt-cli, zulucrypt-gui. All are version 5.0.1.1472658443.fafef92. Downloaded from the zulucrypt website.  I have cryptsetup version 2:1.6.6-5ubuntu2, from the standard xubuntu 16.04 repos. (I have not tweaked my repos at all). The problem remains.

Comment: Zulucrypt v5.0.1 still doesnt work for me. I am going to use ecryptfs instead I think. Thanks.

Comment: I have ubuntu 16.04 next to me and both zuluCrypt and cryptsetup hangs here.

Comment: I have ubuntu 16.04 next to me and both zuluCrypt and cryptsetup hang here. cryptsetup hangs with a error that was reported here[1]. I think the problem you are have is on udev and there is nothing i can do on zuluCrypt's front.
 
[1] http://serverfault.com/questions/739531/arch-cryptsetup-hangs-on-waiting-for-zero

Comment: cryptsetup is working fine for me from the command line, although like I say I can then only use the encrypted volumes with the cryptseup cli. I have moved over to ecryptfs and it gives me what I need, although I will keep my eye on this and check zulucrypt from time to time. I appreciate you getting back to me. Thanks.

Comment: Just tried zuluCrypt packages from the project's page on ubuntu 16.10 and they work just fine. I think there is a permission problem on ubuntu packages as shipped by ubuntu and i am working on a fix now.The problems where carried over to packages i distribute.

While using packages i distribute,first delete "~/.zuluCrypt" and "~/.zuluCrypt-socket" folders and then start zuluCrypt and it should now work. 

You can use my other project named "SiriKali"[1] to manage your ecryptfs volumes using a GUI.I tested it on ubuntu 16.10.

[1] https://mhogomchungu.github.io/sirikali/